# Is it possible to change the configuration of visual studio according to the startup project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am having one solution with multiple projects.

I am basically creating building blocks to build more complicated projects later on. These projects are sometimes dependent on one another, thought I am trying to keep it losely coupled.

It is sometimes necessary to debug one of the projects to test whether certain functions actually behave the way they should. ( *I am going to create test projects for each individual project in the future.* ).

Since they are all **.lib** files, everytime I make a certain project the **startup project** to test it, I need to switch the configuration properties to create a **.exe** file otherwise it wont run.

Is there a way to change the configuration of your projects based on what project is the startup project? So that I can instantly run this instead of manually changing the properties everytime I take a differnt startup project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plan won't work the way you want. But I suppose you could add an extra project that can load the correct lib file and launch it. Then in the debug settings of each lib project specify that debugging will launch your extra project with the path to the lib to load as an argument.

It will require a small custom project, but will make your life easier. It'll look something like this in the debug settings:

[image]